# Experiencing an issue with the .save() function in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I am using Node.js, Express, and MongoDB for a project and in MongoDB, `.save()` is not working.

index.js file code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//middleware;
app.use(express.json()); //for json files;
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));

//routing paths;
const authUser = require("./routes/auth");

// for secrets keys;
dotenv.config();

//Connecting to Mongoose;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_PATH, {
    userNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDb");
}
)

app.use("/api/auth", authUser);

app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log("Server is Running...");
}
)
```

Model file name User.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema  = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    }
});

const User= mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

auth.js file

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//for register;
router.get("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const newuser = new User({
            username: "herovinay",
            password: "herovinay"
        });
        
       newuser.save((err)=> {
           if (err) {
               res.status(500).json({ msg: "internal error is here"});
            } 
            else {
               res.status(200).json({ msg: "Data saved successfully..." });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send("second error is here");
    }
   
})

module.exports = router;
```

When accessing `localhost:9000/api/auth/register`, the output is `msg: "internal error is here"`.

Screenshot of output:

[image: this is the output image]

Every time I tried to hit that request, the same error came over and over again.

I tried everything and was unable to save my data to the MongoDB cluster.

Comment: _`newuser.save((err)=>`_ ... what is `err`?

Comment: `newuser.save((err)=> {` before this line add `await` keyword and i think you need to use the `post` method to save the data instead of `get` method

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what you have tried previously, and to detail some helpful debugging information, such as the value of `err` in the `save` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `get` method to `post`. to create new data in the server the `post` method is used. and also add the `await` keyword before the `newuser.save()`,
here is a example.

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//for register;
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const newuser = new User({
            username: "herovinay",
            password: "herovinay"
        });
        
      await newuser.save((err)=> {
           if (err) {
               res.status(500).json({ msg: "internal error is here"});
            } 
            else {
               res.status(200).json({ msg: "Data saved successfully..." });
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send("second error is here");
    }
   
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but still not working

Comment: log the `err.message` it will help to find what the actual problem is.